# Create a marker in the bottom right corner of the map

Tags: leaflet

I try to set a marker when on the bottom right of my map no matter which zoom level i have, similar to a control where i can set the position to 'bottomright'. What i want to achieve is to show a circle everytime a marker is dragged so i am able to drop the marker in that circle. What i tried so far is this:

```
private createDropZone() {
    const mapBounds = this.map.getBounds();

    const x = mapBounds.getSouthEast();

    const lat = x.lat - 0.02;
    const long = x.lng - 0.02;

    this.dropZone = new L.CircleMarker(new L.LatLng(lat, long), {
      color: '#f27e00',
      fillColor: '#f27e00',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      radius: 50,
    });

    this.dropZone.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

So as i you can i am subtract 0.02 from the south east bound of the map but of course this will only work on one zoom level. If its not possible to draw it on the same position in the right bottom corner it would help if someone give me hint how i can draw a marker relativ to the given marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map's `.latLngToContainerPoint` method to convert lat,lng coordinate to container pixel coordinate, subtract pixel offset (which is zoom independent) and convert pixel coordinate back to lat,lng with `.containerPointToLatLng` method:

```
private createDropZone() {
  const mapBounds = this.map.getBounds();

  const x = mapBounds.getSouthEast();
  const p = this.map.latLngToContainerPoint(x);
  const p_WithOffset = p.subtract(L.point(70, 70));
  const x_WithOffset = this.map.containerPointToLatLng(p_WithOffset);

  this.dropZone = new L.CircleMarker(x_WithOffset, {
    color: '#f27e00',
    fillColor: '#f27e00',
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    radius: 50,
  });

  this.dropZone.addTo(this.map);
}
```

Comment: That's working perfectly, thank you so much =) I completely missed the substract method